# Bridging: OpenBSD vs Linux

Tags: linux, bridge, openbsd

The bridge interface under Linux is quite dumb. In the end, it's just very inconvenient to use: you have to delete all IP configurations from the attached interfaces and somehow migrate the configuration to the bridge interface. I don't understand why (it doesn't make sense at all - normally, a bridge is not an endpoint for communication).

OpenBSD is much better; a bridge interface acts exactly like a physical switch. You create it, add the interfaces and you're done. Is it somehow possible to get similar behavior in Linux?

Comment: The problem you're facing is that BSD's bridge was designed to be a bridge, with a few switching features added later. Linux's bridge was designed to be a switch, but I'm not sure they ever really got there.

Answer (score 4):

Bridges in Linux actually behave *exactly* like a physical switch.

Hey, let's take a look at my physical switch now. Can't get much switchier than a Cisco switch, right?

```
core-sw1#sh ip int brief
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Vlan2                  192.168.0.2     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
Vlan53                 10.53.0.2       YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

Hmm… on my Cisco switch the IP addresses are actually assigned to… the bridge interface. Not a single port.

Yep, you're thinking about it wrong. Consider what an IP address assigned to a single interface on a bridge would *mean*.

Answer (score 1):

you can use openvswitch in bridge mode.